# CSS class doesn't set expected color on links

Tags: php, html, css, url, hyperlink

I use some code to turn urls into working links with php.

But the css class I am using doesnt work when the url ends with *.html

The php seems to work fine but to give more info I'll post it here:

```
// turn http urls into working links
$message = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)','<a href=\'\\1\' class=\'topicurl\' target=\'_blank\'>\\1</a>', $message);
```

The css also seems to work fine most of the time:

```
a.topicurl:link {
    color:#cd4f12;
}
```

And here a screenshot of what is going wrong:

http://img149.imageshack.us/img149/5305/csstrouble.jpg

Comment: What browser? All browsers? Could we see the actual markup (since that's what actually matters)?

Comment: [`eregi_replace()`](http://php.net/eregi_replace) is deprecated. You probably want to switch to PCRE.

Comment: PHP4 must die. Use preg_replace() instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that you already visited the url that ends in .html? I think it would not get matched by `a.topicurl:link`, but only by `a.topicurl:visited`.

Answer (score 2):

Look into adding styles for A:visited? Here is a more complete reference http://www.echoecho.com/csslinks.htm